# how to kill bottom n procceses in linux

Tags: python, linux, centos

By using `pgrep python` i can filter processes by PID:

```
[@~]$ pgrep python
725886
726128
726379
726816
732699
757708
769148
```

How can I kill first n processes in one line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter and pass to kill.

```
pgrep python | head -n $n | xargs kill
```